# How to change Power BI Sort by date instead of alphabetically?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have been learning how to use Power BI and I have ran into some problems. My current problem is on my stacked bar chart. First is that my legend is sorted alphabetically instead of by date as it is entered on excel. The second problem is when I go down the hierarchy to sort by "Jobs" they are sorted alphabetically instead of by date again. I have included 2 screen grabs to show what I mean. Thank you in advance for any help.

[image: Legend]

[image: "Jobs"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First go to the Data View, choose your talbe and select the column you want to sort. Then you have to select "Column Tools" and "Sort by Column". Finally select the column you want to use to sort your selected column.